# TV mount on wood panel

Tags: mount

I want to mount a 50lb TV on top of the fireplace. Panel is made of 3/4" ptocessed wood and 5" gap between the panel and bricks. There mount manufacturer does not suggest using toggle boult anchor. I could not find any 7" tapcon screws and even I am unsure that is a good idea to use such a long screw. What options  do I have?

[image]
[image]
[image]

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: [This question](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/195804/how-to-mount-tv-on-brick?rq=1) is similar. Its comments and answers provide useful information. In short, you'll have to remove at least some of the processed wood panel to expose some of the brick face, and build a structure that will hold your TV 5+ inches away from the brick face. You'll have to pay attention to the type of bricks, and may end up having to fabricate a metal cage that will bolt (at multiple places) to the brick, and provide a "face" 5+ inches out from the brick wall to which you can bolt the TV mount.

Comment: @DavidRecallsMonica Maybe. But if the "3/4" processed wood" is more like heavy plywood and less like cardboard then it may be plenty strong enough to hold a 50lb. TV without reinforcement.

Comment: @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact I agree.  The phrase "processed wood" is pretty vague, and we also don't know how it's mounted to whatever holds it in place.

Comment: @DavidRecallsMonica Hence "if" and "may be".

Comment: Nice suggestions, thanks David and manassehkatz.

Comment: As the mount has an ATM of 18", manufacturer emailed me that it should not be installed on the panel. What about adding two 8' red head anchor screws to the bricks in addition to the other four screws to those panel

Comment: Is "ptocessed" wood plywood, or particle board, or MDF, or something else?  How is the panel in question supported, itself?

Comment: What is an "ATM of 18 inches"? I'm sure you're doing this on your phone which is "helpfully" correcting your spelling to cause you to post gibberish. _Please_ take a moment to proofread before posting.

Comment: Is the wall on which you want to mount this all brick, or is it a wood stud wall with a (thin or full thickness) brick veneer? If it's a wood stud wall, just drill through the brick until you find studs then attach your TV to the wood behind. The brick should be strong enough to support the very long screws going through it. If it's a full brick wall, you may consider some sort of appropriate epoxy to fill larger holes to embed threaded rod into and use that as your bolt, attaching the mount with nuts, or epoxy the board to the brick and screw into the board.

Comment: The wall around thr house are we 4" concrete blocks (photo) but here for the fireplace tgey used bricks.

Comment: The wood seems to be 3/4 MDF. I am unsure how they attach it to the  chimney. I dont see screws because of painting.

Comment: @FreeMan The "arm" not ATM. Sorry for the typo. Stackexchange does not allow me to edit comments.

Comment: They allow editing within the first 5 minutes of posting a comment! Since the "wood" is MDF, I would be cautious about hanging much on it. Screws (even proper MDF screws) will have a propensity to want to pull out, especially with a TV hanging 18" from the wall when the mount is extended and somebody breathes in the general vicinity. That's a fair bit of weight and expense to trust to MDF. I'd replace it with quality plywood before hanging a TV from it.

Comment: @FreeMan what about adding two additional long 7" screws from the other places of mount to the bricks? I can replace all other toggle bolts with long screws to the brick but I have two concerns: 1-2" insider the brick can handle the torque coming from the rest of screw 5"? And secondly, i made a 5/8 holes in that panel. Socrews do not have any support from wood hole. Thee would be angled from the brick to the mount hole.

Answer (score 2):

For a 50lb TV you could glue a 3/4 plywood sheet against the paneling as reinforcement, and attach the mount to it with the supplied screws. The sheet should be as wide and tall as possible, where it is covered by the TV. Stay within the current flute (routed grooves in panel).

Use 2in blobs of construction adhesive in a 12-in spaced grid. Reinforce with screws into MDF.

No need to have screws reach into brick.

Paint it white to match.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a ceiling mount right in front of that space, the TV will fall into same spacial location. Anyways if that's the mount you're using the one shown in picture you may want to buy a wider one so the weight is better distributed, 50lbs isnt alot. That plywood reinforcement would work, not with lag screws.

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by "not with lag screws". They're often recommended for attaching the plywood to studs (or joists) and are usually provided by the mount manufacturer for attaching the mount, so that statement seems inconsistent with the "conventional wisdom".